# Assimp axis conversion

Tags: c++, opengl, linear-algebra, assimp

Assimp converts the imported scene from Z-up to Y-up with a rotation matrix in the root node; this is fine for displaying but makes scripting objects a nightmare.

Is there a way around this? Is it possible in some way to manually convert every object? I think in that case the matrices should be converted too.

Comment: *Is it possible in some way to manually convert every object?* - yes, of course. If it only changes the rotation matrix, though, why don't you simply change it there?

Comment: Because in this way scripting objects must be done with Z-up

Comment: You could bake the rotation into the vertex data that is read in and then undo the rotation in the matrix. This will of course slow down the reading of the scene depending on amount of vertices.

Comment: I am not sure it is that easy. Some nodes could carry local (Z-up) transformations like a rotation matrix.